# Graphics not showing up in C#

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I have a picturebox that has an image in it and a top of this image I am drawing some ellipses. However, only some of the ellipses show up. Code looks something like this:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(pictureBox1.Handle); 
g.FillEllipse(redBrush, rfidNode1.readerPos.X, rfidNode1.readerPos.Y, 15, 15);
```

EDIT: I'm sorry I copied and pasted the last line twice...so there is only one line that fills the ellipse. Also, x and y are within the range of the picture box.

Comment: Filling it twice wont make it show twice... What behavior do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try something like this? (change the dimensions if needed)

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
g.FillEllipse(redBrush, rfidNode1.readerPos.X, rfidNode1.readerPos.Y, 15, 15);
pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
```

Or maybe I missed your intentions?

Comment: Yes, this creates the image (to serve as a buffer) on which you then do all the graphics you need. Then when you are done with drawing, you put the image into the PictureBox (via Image property). I think this is somewhat faster because the picture is rendered on screen only once, and not after each drawing operation. But it all depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If the X and Y are same, you are drawing two ellipses one on top another, so only the last is visible. Also, it could be that the X and Y are out of bounds of picture box ?

Answer (score 0):

try to override the paint event and place there your painting code. drawing processes run very often, and then your graphic just gets overdrawn.

[Tutorial - Drawing with C#](http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial50_Drawing-with-Csharp.html)

Answer (score 0):

For drawing on a control, try to register with the paint-event and use the graphics object provided in the paint event args.

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) for details and an example.

Answer (score -1):

I' m not very sure if it really possible in secure way draw over picture box. Secure I mean: to be sure that all your ellipses are visible when you want. If you want some custom behaviuor, PictureBox is not so good solution, by me.

Like a solution I would suggest to draw an image manually in place where now you have picture box.

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: how would i draw an image manually? is there something wrong with drawing on the picture box??

Comment: @Jonatan: there is nothing wrong by using picturebox, in general, but at the moment you want to customize something, it's difficult to manage, as you need to domain the OS message pumping in different situations that could happen, and you don't have full control over it, or at least it's difficult to do. Drawing manually: by using GDI+. Read a little bit about GDI+ and after judge what is possible and what is not.